# Create java object in C in Android Ndk

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a Java class

```
class Book{
   String bookId;
   String bookName;
   public Book(String bookId, String bookName){
       this.bookId=bookId;
       this.bookName=bookName;
   }

}
```

I want to create object of class Book in JNI.

```
cid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, bookClass, "<init>", "([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V");
```

But the problem is that constructor cannot be found. How to fix it? What is the right method signature?

Answer (score 1):

You're very close - In the method signature, your first argument is specified as an array, but in Java it is not an array. Remove the first square bracket.

```
cid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, bookClass, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V");
```

If that doesn't work you should confirm that `bookClass` is valid (not `NULL`).

Comment: Strange but it doesn't work. bookClass is valid, I do FindClass check before getting method id.

Comment: @user1379574 Are you checking if the result of `FindClass` is valid? I.e. checking if `bookClass` is not NULL?

Comment: yes. I'm sorry, it works! I just tested wrong. Everything is fine, thank you much!